# How to plot a table containing counts by class in R?

Tags: r, plot

How do you visulize in R this kind of table, where x is the class and y the number of occurences in the class?
I want to visualize the distribution but all I manage to do is a barplot (putting y into a vector), so it doesn't use the info of x. I can add the tags afterwards but is there a better way to proceed and directly use this kind of format.
Plus, if I have thousands of class, how can I just plot them with larger bins that the one in the table? (example here this could be plotting just two class <50 and >50).

```
x   y
100 1954
90  106
80  700
70  27
60  861
50  32
40  5491
30  936
20  7364
10  408
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `barplot`

```
barplot(y~x, df)
```

Or in `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_col()
```

---

If you need only two categories, you can create new column and then use `aggregate`.

```
df$class <- ifelse(df$x > 50, 'less than 50', 'higher than 50')
barplot(y~class, aggregate(y~class, df, sum))
```

Answer (score 1):

Following @Ronak Shah said, you can make graph. For many classes, you may use `cut`. For example, split your data as >50 and <50,

```
df %>%
  mutate(grp = cut(V1,2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(grp, V2)) + geom_col()
```

will make bar graph.[image]

If your first column is a factor in your data, you might need to add `as.numeric(first column)` before that.